# Conditional hide/show widget of kanban view .Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I am trying to hide the widget of statusbar  based on a boolean field value.
For 'state1' ; it works fine , but for 'state' , the widget option is not updated in kanban view when changing it from statusbar.
Here is my code :

```
field = fields.Boolean(default=False)

state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('done', 'Done'),
        ('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),

    ], default='draft')

state1 = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('valid', 'Valid'),
])
```

***Kanban view:***

```
<field name="state1" widget="statusbar"
                           statusbar_visible="draft,valid"
                           attrs="{'invisible':[('field', '!=', True)]}"/>

<field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="done,progress,cancelled,draft"
                           attrs="{'invisible':[('field', '=', True)]}"/>
    
<kanban class="o_kanban_mobile">
<t t-if="field == True">
        <field name="state1"  widget="label_selection" options="{'classes': {'draft': 'default','valid': 'default'}}" />
    </t>
<t t-elif="field == False">
         <field name="state"  widget="label_selection" options="{'classes': {'draft': 'default','progress': 'default','done': 'default', 'cancelled': 'default'}}"/>
```